# Adobe Flex static analysis tool

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, testing, static-analysis

Can anyone recommend a static analysis/code complexity/code metrics tool for Adobe Flex (MXML and Actionscript)? Something like Sonar or Clover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [FlexPMD](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD) can be an answer.

> FlexPMD is a tool that helps to improve code quality by auditing any AS3/Flex source directory and detecting common bad practices, such as:
>
> - Unused code (functions, variables, constants, etc.)
> - Inefficient code (misuse of dynamic filters, heavy constructors, etc.)
> - Over-complex code (nested loops, too many conditionals, etc.)
> - Over-long code (classes, methods, etc.)
> - Incorrect use of the Flex component lifecycle (commitProperties, etc.)

Comment: Thanks thats what I ended up coming up with too.

Answer (score 0):

Sonar Flex Plugin looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe's [Flex PMD](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD) is a good start.